# Automatic Code Update for Exception Handling in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

This older syntax was removed in Python 3:

```
try:
    ...
except MyException, exc:    # Don't do that!
    ...
```

New

```
try:
    ...
except MyException as exc:
    ...
```

I checked how many times the old syntax gets used in the code I work on:

```
find */* -name '*.py'|xargs grep 'except.*,.*:'| wc -l
551
```

Wow, that's a lot

Is there a way to automated this particular Python2 to Python3 update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... answering my own question. I found the `futurize` from [python-future](http://python-future.org/automatic_conversion.html):

```
futurize --write --nobackups --fix lib2to3.fixes.fix_except src/mylib/
```

It supports a lot of other fixes, but today I want to focus in the exception handling.

It works well and saves me a lot of time :-)